# Combine(concatenate) rows based on dates via SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, teradata

I have the following table.

```
Animal  Vaccine_Date    Vaccine
Dog     1/1/2016        x
Dog     2/1/2016        y
Dog     2/1/2016        z
Cat     2/1/2016        y
Cat     2/1/2016        z
```

I want to be able to combine vaccines that are on the same animal and same date, so that they appear in the same cell.  The table below is what the desired end result would be.

```
Animal  Vaccine_Date    Vaccine
Dog     1/1/2016        x
Dog     2/1/2016        y,z
Cat     2/1/2016        y,z
```

I have tried to create a volatile table to do so but I am not having any luck and I don't think Teradata recognizes the Group_concat.

Comment: Is there a known maximum of rows to combine?

Comment: There is not a maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED 20180419**

Teradata (not sure which version) has added [XMLAGG](https://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/Teradata_Data_Types/B035-1140-160K/ssm1472241245699.html) which would be a better choice here than recursive)

---

**Original answer:**

Teradata doesn't have `group_concat`/`listagg` functionality. There are a couple of workarounds. My favorite is to use a recursive CTE. It's not terribly efficient, but it's well documented and supported functionality.

In your case:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recCTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Animal, 
            Vaccine_Date,
            CAST(min(Vaccine) as VARCHAR(50)) as vaccine_list, --big enough to hold concatenated list 
            1 as depth, --used to determine the largest/last group_concate (the full group) in the final SELECT
            Vaccine

        FROM table
        GROUP BY 1,2


        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            recCTE.Animal,
            recCTE.Vaccine_Date,
            recCTE.Vaccine || ',' || table.Vaccine
            recCTE.depth + ,
            table.Vaccine
        FROM recCTE 
            INNER JOIN table ON
                recCTE.Animal = table.Animal AND
                recCTE.Vaccine_Date =  Table.Vaccine_Date
                table.vaccine > recCTE.vaccine
    )

    --Now select the result with the largest depth for each animal/vaccine_date combo
    SELECT * FROM recCTE
    QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY animal,vaccine_date ORDER BY depth desc) = 1
```

You may have to tweak that a little bit (possibly trim the vaccine values before concatenating and whatnot), but it should get you in the ballpark. You can check out the recursive CTE documentation [at this link](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/db_ttu_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.061.html), but it's pretty dry. There are a lot of tutorials out there too, if you are unfamiliar. Teradata's implementation of recursive CTE is very similar to T-SQL and PostgresSQL's implementation as well.

As another option you can check out the as-of-yet undocumented `tdstats.udfconcat()` as explained by the extremely knowledgable @dnoeth in [this thread](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/UDFCONCAT/m-p/23616) on Teradata Community website.

Comment: What does the "min" do in CAST(min(Vaccine) as VARCHAR(50))?  I was receiving an error due to this, I had to change it to CAST(min(Vaccine) as VARCHAR(50)) as vaccine.

Comment: `Min()` is selecting the minimum vaccine (ordered lexicographical) for each `Animal`/`Vaccine_Date` combination in the first query, which is the recursive seed, or the query that acts as the starting point for the recursive lookup. In the next `SELECT` statement, we join by only grabbing `vaccine` records that are larger than the value grabbed in the previous iteration. Slowly this builds up until there is one record that has all of the `vaccine` records for each `animal`/`vaccine_date` combination; which is what is selected in the final select statement from the recursive cte.

Comment: I see.  That makes sense.  when I run it I get the following error. "Teradata exception: [Teradata Database] [3707] Syntax error, expected something like ')' between the word 'recCTE' and '.'."  Are you able to call "recCTE" after the "Union all"  even the the recursive statement is still open?

Comment: Here is the actual code I am using, if it helps.Never mind it is too many characters and I can't delete comment

Comment: Yep! You have to have the recursive CTE in the second statement inside the recursive CTE, which is what makes it recursive. Crazy, right? The top statement inside executes once and builds a result set, then the second statement is called over and over again until the INNER JOIN (where join itself to the `table`) is exhausted and returns nothing. It's like a loop in SQL and super powerful. Just check the format of the query and make sure everything is up to snuff (commas in the right place, periods in the right place, etc).

Comment: I was able to get the query to run.  I had to change "1 as depth" to "cast( 1 as int) as depth".  But I am getting a spooling space error.  I imported the table in my OP into Teradata to run and I am still getting a spooling space error.  It seems that it keeps looping and I am not sure what is causing it.

Comment: Yea... sounds like an endless loop, for sure. So.. to stop a recursive query from cycling endlessly, it's good practice to put something like `WHERE recCTE.depth < 15` (or whatever your max number of concats might feel right) in that second `SELECT` statement (the recursive term). Then the query will at least finish and you can see what it's spitting out and understand why it's cycling infinitely. Which is pretty common with these beasts.

Comment: That worked like a charm!  However, when I set it to 5 it repeats the last found vaccine till five if there is more than one vaccine.  For example, even though cat should only show "y,z" for vaccine, it shows "y,z,z,z,z,z".  Any ideas on this one?

Comment: The ON clause of the recursive term should prevent that: `table.vaccine > recCTE.vaccine`. essentially not allowing in the same vaccine as the previous iteration unless it's greater than the previous iteration's vaccine.

Comment: In the example table, since z is greater than y, it keeps repeating is my guess.

Comment: Oh geez. Yea... Sorry it's been a long day. I'm on mobile now so I can't type up the fix, but basically in the first select bring in the vaccine into a new column then in the second select bring in the table.vaccine to the same column and reference that in the inequality. That was a dumb mistake. :(

Comment: So I probably spent more time on this than I should have this weekend lol.  I am not sure I am following what you are saying.  When I add the "vaccine" to both select statements, respectively, and reference the inequality, I no longer get the combine vaccines, I only get the minimum vaccine for each animal for each day rather than all vaccines for each animal for each day.

Comment: Sorry for the wait. I've added in the column like I was thinking. The inequality now compares the last vaccine found against the list of possible vaccines in the <table> in an inequality, which should do the trick.

Comment: I asked a new question as I was not able to get it to work and I was not able to post what I wanted in the 500 character limit.  I referenced this post in the new post as well as added the updated code that you typed above.  I believe your answer to be correct and I am simply entering a single line of code incorrectly.  If you get a chance can you please visit my new post at the following address:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39575359/combining-rows-in-sql-viia-recursive-query

Answer (score 0):

Try this. STUFF function is an ideal for such situations:

```
  SELECT
     Animal, Vaccine_Date,
     STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Vaccine
          FROM TableName
          WHERE Animal = a.Animal AND Vaccine_Date = a.Vaccine_Date
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS VaccineList
FROM TableName AS a
GROUP BY Animal, Vaccine_Date
```

Comment: afaik Teradata does not have support the t-sql `STUFF()` function.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this Query,

```
  SELECT 
   Animal,Vaccine_Date,
   LISTAGG(Vaccine, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Vaccine) "names"
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY Vaccine
```

Hope you got it

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` functionality is not built into Teradata

Comment: Modified query work in oracle sql. LISTAGG is the function used

Comment: Oracle is also not Teradata